# Postgres group by day of month, ActiveRecord(Rails) returns array with nil ids while database query works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I want to retrieve a single row corresponding to each day

```
result=Attendance.where("created_at > ? and created_at < ?",business_day_start,business_day_end).group("day").select("to_char(created_at,'DD') as day")
```

I use the above query on a model with columns created_at and user_id
  ActiveRecord gives me the following result

```
SELECT to_char(created_at,'DD') as day FROM "attendances" WHERE (created_at > '2016-03-06 00:00:00.000000' and created_at < '2016-03-09 23:59:59.999999') GROUP BY day
[#<Attendance:0x007f99fc469a40 id: nil>, #<Attendance:0x007f99fc469860 id: nil>, #<Attendance:0x007f99fc469590 id: nil>]
```

But if I run the same query(obtained from above result) directly in the database(using pgAdmin), I get proper result with a column(day) and 3 rows in it
I am unable to understand where I am going wrong and why is active record returning an array of nil elements?

Comment: Executive summary: try `result.map(&:day)` to see your results. Also, are you sure you want to exclude the `created_at = ?` case? Wouldn't you want to work with a half-open interval rather than a fully open one?

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort, I guess a more descriptive title could help avoid any further duplicates, regarding the open interval, that's just  a part of the whole query, I would keep it in mind while writing the whole query

Comment: Don't feel bad. This duplicate is both hard to find and hard to describe in just the title. I only found it because I know I've answer this question several times and I just used the duplicate a couple days ago.